# Как получить список папок в какой-либо директории

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, мне необходимо получить список папок в какой-либо папке? Ну или как получить список этих папок? Спасибо за помощь

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html, https://javapapers.com/java/walk-file-tree-with-java-nio/

Answer (score 1):

Получение списка двумя способами:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileFilter;
    import java.util.stream.Stream;

    public class Folders {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //stream
            Stream.of(
                    new File(System.getenv("temp"))
                            .listFiles(p -> p.isDirectory())
            ).forEach(
                    (File f) -> System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath())
            );

            //классика
            File[] directories = new File(System.getenv("temp"))
                    .listFiles(new FileFilter() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                            return pathname.isDirectory();
                        }
                    });
            for (File dir : directories) {
                System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если будут вложенные папки, то этот оба этих способа их не обнаружат.

Comment: В вопросе речи о рекурсии не было. Приведенный код полностью покрывает суть вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Может кому пригодиться...
Можно использовать Files.walkTreeFile(Path, SimpleFileVisitor<>()),
Только нужно переопределить нужный нам метод. Так же, можно указать до какого уровня вложенности следует исследовать каталоги

```
List<Path> folders = new ArrayList<>();    
    Files.walkFileTree(file.toPath(), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                    folders.add(dir);
                    return super.postVisitDirectory(dir, exc);
                }
            });
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]